# Remove nodejs/browser specific code in library

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm the maintainer of the following library on github: https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater/blob/master/coffee/docxgen.coffee

I want to maintain a library that works on node and in the browser, however I don't want to have to update two separate repositories.

The ugliest code looks like this:

```
root= global ? window
env= if global? then 'node' else 'browser'

if env=='node'
    global.http= require('http')
    global.https= require('https')
    global.fs= require('fs')
    global.vm = require('vm')
    global.DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser
    global.XMLSerializer= require('xmldom').XMLSerializer
    global.PNG= require('../vendor/pngjs/png-node')
    global.url= require('url')

    ["grid.js","version.js","detector.js","formatinf.js","errorlevel.js","bitmat.js","datablock.js","bmparser.js","datamask.js","rsdecoder.js","gf256poly.js","gf256.js","decoder.js","qrcode.js","findpat.js","alignpat.js","databr.js"].forEach (file) ->
        vm.runInThisContext(global.fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../vendor/jsqrcode/' + file), file)
    ['jszip.js'].forEach (file) ->
        vm.runInThisContext(global.fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../vendor/jszip2.0/dist/' + file), file)

output: (options={}) ->
        if !options.download? then options.download=true
        if !options.name? then options.name="output.docx"
        if !options.type? then options.type="base64"
        result= @zip.generate({type:options.type})
        if options.download
            if env=='node'
                fs.writeFile process.cwd()+'/'+options.name, result, 'base64', (err) ->
                    if err then throw err
            else
                #Be aware that data-uri doesn't work for too big files: More Info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082286/getting-max-data-uri-size-in-javascript
                document.location.href= "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,#{result}"
        result
```

As you can see, they is a lot of specific node/browser js code, and I would like to remove that from the main code, however, I can't find an easy way to do this.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah..

Are you against maintaining 2 repositories or maintaining 2 main files? Honestly I would have 2 main files with a third file ( or more ) containing routines that are host agnostic.

`docxgen_node.coffee` , `docxgen_www.coffee` and `docxgen_common.coffee`

It sounds uncool, but I think in the end, this should be easiest on the eyes.

Other, than that, I would take the opportunity to use that massive ( ugly ) string array to document why you need each library and maybe which versions are usable for your repository:

```
var requiredLibraries = [
  "grid.js",     //Use xyz version, uses abc features
  "version.js",  //...
  "detector.js", //..
  ...
]

requiredLibraries.forEach (file) ->
    vm.runInThisContext(global.fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../vendor/jsqrcode/' + file), file)
```

Comment: Maintaning two specific files and one host agnostic is ok I think